# Recommended docker images , in .net core application

Tags: docker

I am currently using "mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet" as the environment for the application.

The app works, but when I want to adjust some settings, I find that there are many things missing, such as time zone, language.

Is there a suitable image to use?

Comment: The aspnet images are the recommended images to use. It's my impression that most people prefer to run their containers using UTC and don't set timezones in the containers. If you want to run your container using a different timezone, you can easily modify your image to do so.

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: You just need to set the TZ environment variable. If I run `docker run -e TZ=Europe/Copenhagen --rm mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 date` it prints out the date and time in my local timezone.